# Weird behavior of the task bar while showing a secondary window running on a another thread

Tags: c#, wpf

I have created a busy box with an indeterminate progress bar which runs on a different thread to show up whenever the main UI becomes unresponsive during heavy tasks. Now the problem is every time i show the busy widow, it brings start menu out to the front while the main window of the application running in full screen and goes back to normal right after the busy window closes.

[Start menu comes to front whenever i show the busy window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FyhW7.png)

[Application goes back to full screen once the busy window closes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0PONf.png)

I could have done this easily using background workers everywhere in my code, but what i wanted was a reusable solution. can someone explain me why this happens? Suggestions are welcome.

Here's my class definition of the BusyBox

```
    class BusyBox
    {
    static BusyBoxWindow BbwP;
    static Thread WindowThread;

    public static void ShowBusy()
    {
    if (WindowThread == null)
        {
            WindowThread = new System.Threading.Thread(() =>
            {
                SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(new DispatcherSynchronizationContext(Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher));
                BbwP = new BusyBoxWindow();
                /*BbwP.Owner = HomeWindow.HomeW;*/  // this line throws the exception "The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it"
                BbwP.Show();

                BbwP.Closed += (s, e) =>
                {
                    Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvokeShutdown(DispatcherPriority.Background);
                };

                System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run();

            });
            WindowThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
            WindowThread.Start();
        }
        else
        {
            BbwP.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => { BbwP.Show(); }));
        }
    }

    public static void CloseBusy()
    {
        BbwP.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => { BbwP.Hide(); }));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that you need a parent/child relationship between the windows in order for it to know that the full-screen window is still on top. But that means that the two UI threads both need to be pumping messages to work correctly. Which can't work because you've said that you're blocking the UI thread of the parent.

The solution (as you seem to already be aware) is to not block the UI thread and let it continue to do UI things and to move the heavy work off onto other threads - whether that be by Background workers, `Task.Run()` or whatever other means you find appropriate.

Comment: Actually i can't set the Owner property of the busy window as i get "The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it" exception at run time. Is there anyway i can set the owner property of a window that belongs to another thread? I have updated my question with my BusyBox class attached, please take a look and help me out. Thank you.

Comment: It's just not going to work if one of your UI threads is kept busy. And once you've *resolved* that, you don't *need* a second thread and then Parent/Owner issues won't be concerned about cross-threading issues.

Comment: So i might just have to try the other way by keeping the threads busy. thank you by the way (Y).

Answer (score 0):

Weird behavior of the 'Task Bar' went away after i set the ShowInTaskbar property of the Busy window to false. Thanks everyone for shedding some light on my matter!